# Listening to window onresize, excluding jquery dialog's onresize

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, resize

I need to listen to the window.onresize event, so, using jquery, I'm doing the following

```
$(window).resize(...)
```

When I open a jquery ui resizable dialog and it is resized, the window onresize is triggered too, but I don't want to react to this event. How can achieve this?

I need to listen to window onresize to resize internal panels when the size of the window changes

Comment: I can't guarantee that this will work, however you could try attaching a callback handler that calls `stopPropagation()` on the event for the resizable `resize` event. That should hopefully prevent it from bubbling all the way up to the window.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment a small amount: Try calling `event.stopPropagation()` in the `resize` callback handler passed to the `resize` property when setting up your resizable dialog. Code would look something like this:

```
$('selector-for-dialog').resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        // do some stuff to react to this event here
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't work, but doing $('selector-for-dialog').dialog({  resize: function(event, ui) ... injects the resize fun into the dialog. That fun. is called onresize, but it is called AFTER the window resize listener!! So, sadly this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery 1.7.2 I used this code that works on older IE browsers as well as Chrome...

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).prop("tagName") == "DIV") {return;}  // tag causing event is a div (i.e not the window)
    console.log("resize");
});
```

This might have to be adapted if the element resized is something else than a